# Subquery does not work, but substituting subquery results does

Tags: mysql, subquery

Okay, I am using the `states` table found [here](http://kimbriggs.com/computers/computer-notes/mysql-notes/mysql-create-state-table.file)

...AND A TABLE `default_item` defined:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `default_item` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `States` varchar(200) NOT NULL DEFAULT '""'
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=637 ;

INSERT INTO `default_Item` (`id` `States`) VALUES
(636, '''AR'',''CA''');
```

I have a field in a table that contains a list of State abbreviations, the field is "States", so if I select one of those fields as example:

```
SELECT `States`
FROM `default_item` 
WHERE `id`=636
```

This returns via PHPMyAdmin:

```
'AR','CA'
```

I want to be able to replace the state abbreviations with the state names from the table 'state' cited above.  If I use:

```
SELECT group_concat( `state` )
FROM `state`
WHERE `state_abbr`
IN (
'AR', 'CA'
)
```

It works!  I get:

```
Arkansas,California
```

But if I use the subquery...

```
SELECT group_concat( `state` )
FROM `state`
WHERE `state_abbr`
IN (
SELECT `States`
FROM `default_item` 
WHERE `id`=636
)
```

...this returns NULL.

Have been searching for some hint as to what I am doing wrong, but cannot seem to find the trick.  Anyone have a solution?

Comment: Understanding the structure and content of the default_item table is the key to understanding your problem. Please share its definition and some sample data, like you did with the states table.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT group_concat( `state` )
FROM `state`
WHERE `state_abbr`
IN (
SELECT `States` FROM `default_item` WHERE `id`='636')
```

'636'

you can ask here alive

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7bd88/4

where is table default_item

Comment: Trying to use SQL fiddle to add the 'default_item' table, but I'm getting an error

Answer (score 1):

Your first query returns a string "AR, CA" and not a list of two strings. Your compound query when substituting the subquery actually looks like this:

```
SELECT group_concat( `state` )
FROM `state`
WHERE `state_abbr`
IN (
  "AR, CA"
)
```

That's why it doesn't work.